# 2010 Chevy Camaro LT V6 error code: p0009

Tags: chevrolet, camaro

Does anyone know how to fix the error code p0009 on a 2010 Camaro because I been researching for a solution but can't find one so please someone help me!

Comment: What does the code p0009 mean? Have you cleared it and does it return?

Comment: I'm sure you could search for OBD p0009 and come up with results, what have you tried and what do you not understand?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an explanation of what P0009 means:

[2010 Camaro P0009 Code](https://www.autoblog.com/2016/03/17/p0009-obd-ii-trouble-code-engine-positions-system-performance-b/#:%7E:text=P0009%20is%20a%20generic%20OBD,crankshaft%20and%20camshaft(s).)

Here is the stated cause:

[image: P0009 Code Causes]

Here is what to do about it:

[image: P0009 Solutions]

Comment: Why did you cut/paste images into your answer? This makes it non-searchable. The images are quite blurry as well.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 perhaps to stop it being a link only answer?

Comment: @SolarMike - Perhaps if there's more than a link and a couple of images, it wouldn't be a "link only" answer as it is now. Copying the information which is shown in the images is by far the better way to go.